# What could be causing processes to be suspended?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, signals

This excerpt from a shell session says it all:

```
brandon@Air ~ % brew upgrade rust
```

...

```
==> Pouring rust--1.75.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
[1]  + 76816 suspended (signal)  brew upgrade rust
brandon@Air ~ % fg
[1]  + 76816 continued  brew upgrade rust
[1]  + 76816 suspended (signal)  brew upgrade rust
brandon@Air ~ % fg
[1]  + 76816 continued  brew upgrade rust
[1]  + 76816 suspended (signal)  brew upgrade rust
brandon@Air ~ % fg
[1]  + 76816 continued  brew upgrade rust
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
##O=-#     #                                                                                                                                                                                   
==> Caveats
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rust/1.75.0: 39,169 files, 851.7MB
==> Running `brew cleanup rust`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
Removing: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rust/1.74.0... (39,060 files, 951.5MB)
```

The process (seemingly) randomly just suspended itself.  I entered `fg` but it immediately was suspended again. This happened several times.

But it happens at unpredictable times, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot.  If I change a variable that I suspect to be involved, and nothing happens, it doesn't prove anything since it doesn't always occur under any specific obvious circumstances.

Where should I look for possible clues or solutions?

I've seen across different versions of both Bash and Zsh.  I've seen it inside and outside of tmux.  I've seen it using iTerm and Kitty and Warp and Terminal.app.

I'm using macOS 12.6.6 (21G646) on an M1 Air.

Comment: "_If I change a variable that I suspect to be involved..._" - what variable? Please don't leave us guessing but instead put it into your question

Comment: Possibly same as [Can't restart a suspended process](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/757413). Are you using AppPolice?

Comment: That `(signal)` indicates the signal is SIGSTOP, not SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, SIGTSTP, so something is doing a `kill()` with SIGSTOP on the process or process group.

Comment: Just a thought. ... add `set -vx` before starting your initial command? If there  are script file(s) being invoked, then a  `set -x` (`set +x` to disable) AND `export PS4='${LINENO} >'` at the top of each script.  (This probably doesn't apply, but i you can do it, you may see which commands are causing the problem).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas * no but I do use App Tamer, which is similar. I'm disabling it now and I'll see if that makes a difference. Thanks!